# MooTools: Searchquery not same result in IE only

Tags: internet-explorer, dom, search, mootools

I'm new to MooTools , need to change some existing code (normaly i am using jQuery).

When i search the dom with use of MooTools, in IE only I will get other results (invalid results).

Part of html source for example:

```
<a class="dmnmlk" rel="dmnml='post'" /></a>
<a href="#" /></a>
<a href="#" /></a>
<a class="blueLink" rel="external" href="http://www.linkedin.com" /></a>
<a rel="external,twitter='txxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',data={'border-color':'#634e42','chrome':'noheader nofooter transparent',polite:'polite',limit:10}" class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/test" /></a>
<a rel="mlink" /></a>
<a rel="mlink" /></a>
<a rel="mlink" /></a>
<a rel="mlink" /></a>
<a><span /></a>
<a rel="mlink" /></a>
<a rel="mlink" class="selected" /></a>
<a rel="mlink" class="selected" /></a>
<a rel="mlink" class="selected" /></a>
<a rel="svg" class="sprites menuLogo" href="#" title="Go to startpage" /></a>
<div class="resources hidden">
   <div class="dialog">
     .............
   <a class="button" rel="modalresult='ok'>OK</a>
   <a class="button" rel="modalresult='cancel'>Cancel</a>
</div>
```

---

```
var aElems = $('a[rel]:not(.resources a[rel],.disabled),a[href*="#"]:not(a[rel])');

alert( aElems.length );
```

In other browser than IE: count is 14
In IE only: count is 2

Im using latest mootools version.

Can somebody explain what is going on? What can i do about this?

**EDIT:** EXPLANATION OF WHAT I TRY TO DO:

I scan links with a rel tag  in html to bind functionality to it. I know you can use the data attribute now in HTML5 but this must work in older IE versions (i use XHTML strict). I do this for several reasons:

- It is fast, scan DOM only once
- Scalability, when rel attribute with a specific name does not exist
  in the html, the  associated function will never be executed
- Compact, all functions can be fitted into one single file without
  conflicts and it is very clean and clear
- Can be used with dynamic stuff ajax, dialogs, functionality can be automatic bind when new html is loaded without the need to design a specific function because it is already specified in the rel attribute.
- Stability, if a function does not exist or rel attribute does not exist, code will not break.

I use this technique for several years now (with jQuery) and it is very handy, i call it 'AjaxQuery' for example:

```
 // Extend the ajaxquery class
TAjaxQuery.prototype.setupPage = function() // Will be called automaticly
{
 var o = this;

o.onAjaxFoundRelAttrMlink = function( oSender, oData ) // Called when rel="mlink" is found
{
  // oData.target    // Target element
  // oData.rel.mlink // parsed rel attribute
  $(oData.target).bind( 'click', function(e) // i know this is jquery
  {
    // do something
  }); 

  // ..... etc
};

};
```

The resources can be dialogs so functionality must be only binded when visible. That's the reason links with a rel attribute in a resource must be NOT binded at startup. A dialog is a dynamic thing. That's why `not(.resources a[rel])` is in the searchquery.

I'll hope you get the idea.

Comment: The code you posted does not look like Mootools. (Which version do you use?) Do you mean you get that behaviour with jQuery in IE and want to do the same with Mootools and stable crossbrowser? Can you make a fiddle with your markup?

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply! Well this code works perfectly in all other browsers (except IE) and yes this also works when using jQuery. For some reason it returns less elements in IE, do i need to do it differently for IE?

Comment: Which version of Mootools do you use? Do you have jQuery library also loaded?

Comment: you need to use $$ in mootools, btw. having said that, there seems to be a problem with this: `a[rel]:not(.resources a[rel],.disabled)` - what is your intent? all a with rel that are not children of a .resources el or have .disabled class? the :not implementation in Slick is old and prior to standardisation. also, you need a reverse combinator to check parent. this breaks in IE10 also. raising a ticket

Comment: raised. https://github.com/mootools/mootools-core/issues/2536 - in the meanwhile, can you explain what you'd like to select from your dom, also provide an example with .resources and .disabled on so we can tweak it and come to a working query?

Comment: for now, you can remove `.resources a[rel]` and it will work - this is invalid as the not context is the matching element (the a with rel) - if you need to drop elements from consideration that are children of `.reources`, apply `.filter(function(a){ return !!a.getParent('.resources') });`, or anchor to a parentnode that does not have that class via doing `.otherClass a[rel]:not(...)` first

Comment: @DimitarChristoff, I would say your comments together qualify as an answer to this question, a very good answer btw. I still have a feeling OP is using jQuery, that selector in jQuery works. But anyway, your comments/answer is the answer for Mootools

Comment: @Erwinus, please post also the element with the class `.resources` to make your code more complete.

Comment: Edit/Added some comments for you folks! Thanks for the replies. I will check Dimitar approach. But can you explain why it is working in other browsers except IE?

Comment: @Erwinus, I ask again, just to have all the info: do you have jQuery loaded in your page where you use `aElems = $(` ?

Comment: Sergio: No, because that is not allowed/wanted. MooTools is latest version you can download. I know that $() = get single element???? is not the same as $$() => get array of elements. But why it is working in other browsers except IE?

Comment: @Erwinus, in Mootools `$` is for id, same as `document.id('elementid')`. Don't you get error in the console for `$` ? Mootools needs `$$`.

Comment: A colleague told me not to use $$ but i think he doesn't know what he is talking about. Weird thing, when using $$() same results. Edit: Okay! I have seen that and doesn't understand why it wants a document.id (firebug reports)